# join count from the same table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, mysql-error-1248

I need to query a table for some amounts Billed, Received, Adjusted but need to join into the table also a count of the samples that where serviced

I could request this separately, but I would like to have the result nicely in one array

This is the query that I thought would work

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(`amount_billed`/1000),2) AS `billed`,
ROUND(SUM(`amount_received`/1000),2) AS `received`, 
ROUND(SUM(`amount_adjusted`/1000),2) AS `adjustment` FROM `acs`.`billing` AS **`amount`**
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(`accession_id`) AS `samples` FROM `acs`.`billing` AS **`count`** 
WHERE year(`count`.`date_billed`) = 2012 AND year(`count`.`date_paid`) = 2012
HAVING COUNT(`accession_id`) > 1) WHERE year(`amount`.`date_billed`) = 2012 AND year(`amount`.`date_paid`) = 2012;
```

but MySQL returns the error:

> Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

I gave all tables an alias for select query `amount` and for the join `count`.

Comment: The derived table from `SELECT count('accession_id').... >1)` in the `INNER JOIN` doesn't have an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `SELECT COUNT(accession_id) AS samples` you are assigning an alias to the single field.

You need to assign a alias to the derived table. You actually miss it.

Try to update the query adding at last:

```
) as table_b;
```

before your semicolon or where the second query ends (this is not clear reading the query right now because you miss to close the `)` that is opened on the inner_join.

Comment: it wont let me when ever i try to mark it it says to low reputation need 15 or more

Comment: You don't have to up vote but to click on the mark under the down arrow:)